# How to disable an html element's hover event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mouseover, jquery-events

I want to disable an element's hover event, is it possible? I want to bind tooltips to some elements and then make sure they are not shown on mouse over but later when I want to show them I can simply call the event and they are shown. In other words, I want to somehow make sure that the event is not called unless I explicitly do so. I am very new to jQuery and I am using clueTip, a plugin for tooltips. The problem is that it doesn't have a method to explicitly show the tooltip (or I did not find one). So my only option is to show it in a callback for the click method. BTW I know it has a property to activate on click but due to some reasons, I cannot use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing an event-handler with jquery: [$(>selector<).off('>eventType<')](http://api.jquery.com/off/)
or [$(>selector<).unbind('>eventType<[, handler(eventObject)])](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/)
and without: [element.removeEventListener(type, listener, useCapture)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.removeEventListener)